# Custom Search Help without criteria fields

Tags: abap, sap-crm

I created a Search Help.
It works good, but there's a problem.
When F4 opens there's criteria fields and buttons which I don't want to see there.

[image]

How can I hide the criteria fields and buttons?

Here are my search help parameters:

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot is useless, it's almost completely blanked out, but it looks like the section above the hit list that is collapsed by default. Correct?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Sandra. You're right.
But I solved my problem.

Comment: It's not sufficient that you "solved [your] problem"; remember that stackoverflow is a [little bit different from other sites](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "[This implies that all posts are **expected to have value for later visitors**, in addition to helping the asker. To enforce that, and to prevent help vampires from making the answerers turn away from the community, low-quality questions and answers are blocked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)". Could you clarify your Q&A for visitors? Thx!

Comment: Can you explain to me, please, what do you mean exactly? My Q is to simple or something else?

Comment: Thx. Simple is not an issue, but quality is (I don't say that yours has a lesser quality than other questions). Future visitors will be thankful if you improve: (1) the 'bad' screenshot; I recognize almost nothing (2) Add a screenshot of your fields definition in the Q (3) Add a screenshot of solution in the A (4) I would talk about the "dialog type" to expand the topic a little bit ("dialog with value restriction") (5) If you need to obfuscate screenshots, use instead a demo search help like SFLIGHT, copy it to ZSFLIGHT and take screenshots of ZSFLIGHT (run SAPBC_DATA_GENERATOR if no data)

Comment: Great. I got you, Sandra. Thanks alot for your explanation. I'll try to fix it in future. 
P.S: I'll change the screenshot and add a normal answer.

Comment: Perfect (to me), thanks! Future visitors should be happy now. I just added one screenshot in the question to show the parameters before.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Search Help Setting, then in Search Help Parameter we should clear (or put 0) the field value in the **SPos** column for those parameters to hide in Criteria area. Then just Save and Activate the Search Help.

[image: Search Help Parameter Should Be like This]

[image: My Search Help View After Parameter Changes]